# Input values in css classes

Tags: html, css

I have some css class like this:

```
.ft-*{
    font-size: .*px;
}
```

Is there anyway to define css whenever I call something like `<div class="ft-16">hello</div>` some property like font size changes to 16? I mean can css input something instead of `*` mark like number,..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. CSS does not support this. Use a CSS preprocessor language such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) for this sort of feature.

Comment: Indeed. Using the loop functionality of `LESS` this can be done easily enough: http://blog.thehippo.de/2012/04/programming/do-a-loop-with-less-css/

Answer (score 1):

For something like this you could need to use a css [preprocesser and Mixins](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

Answer (score 1):

You could use JS to find and define them, but you are probably better off simply taking the time to define the classes you will need and then they are there for when you need them throughout the project.
It probably won't payoff in terms of time in/benefit out.

Just set up a bunch of classes:

```
.ft-12 {}
.ft-14 {}
.ft-16 {}
```

etc etc

It's worth it to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a jQuery aproach:

```
var font_size = temp_css_class.split('-')[1];

$( temp_css_class ).each(function() {
  $(this).css("font-size", font_size + "px");
});
```

Where "temp_css_class" is your class name.

Comment: This is a pretty "dumb" approach. It will be significantly slower than CSS, clutters JavaScript with CSS concerns, and does not apply to elements added to the page after the snippet runs.

Comment: Still the only way to do it without LESS or SASS?

Comment: I'd argue that [@TimPalmer's way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20572198/139010) is better, sans LESS/SASS.